# SQL: How can I select two IDs as two names from the same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and trying to get a handle on joins and referencing.

Databases look like this:

**Players**

```
 id | name
----+-------
  1 | john
  2 | tim
  3 | frank
  4 | tony
  5 | mark
```

**Matches**

```
 id | winner | loser
----+--------+-------
  1 |      2 |     4
  2 |      3 |     4
  3 |      4 |     5
  4 |      1 |     4
```

I want to get this result:

```
 id | winner | loser
----+--------+-------
  1 |    tim |  tony
  2 |  frank |  tony
  3 |   tony |  mark
  4 |   john |  tony
```

So far I can do this:

```
select matches.id, players.name as winner, players.name as loser
  from matches, players 
  where winner = players.id;
```

But if I add `and loser = players.id`, it returns no rows.

I've also tried this:

```
select matches.id, players.name as winner, players.name as loser
  from matches
  join players on matches.winner = players.id
  join players on matches.loser = players.id;
```

which produces `ERROR:  table name "players" specified more than once`.

I have googled this for an hour and can find lots of cases that *almost* get at what I want, but I still can't figure out how to replace two IDs with two names from the same table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
select matches.id, w.name as winner, l.name as loser
 from matches
 join players w on matches.winner = w.id
 join players l on matches.loser = l.id;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I didn't know about the feature where you can put the variables 'w' and 'l' after 'players'. Is there a name for that, so I can look it up and learn more about it?

Comment: It's called alias and used to differentiate tables and shorten your statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to alias the table names so you can specify which join the data should come from.

```
select
    matches.id,
    p1.name as winner,
    p2.name as loser
from matches
  join players p1 on matches.winner = p1.id
  join players p2 on matches.loser = p2.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works — I gave @Tim3880 the tick because their answer was essentially the same and 1 minute earlier :) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your will want to make sure that you join twice on that table and keep the alias correct.

```
SELECT Matches.id, winner.name, loser.name
From Matches
INNER JOIN Players as winner on winner.id = Matches.winner
INNER JOIN Players as loser on loser.id = Matches.winner;
```